# Calculate data with increasing value

Tags: calculus

I have values: 
$A=$amount of modules
$X=$level of modules

Each level "cost" more:
$1$st level cost $0$
$2$nd level cost $100$
$3$rd level cost $200$

And so on.

How can I calculate total cost if I have $35$ modules on $67$ level? What such equation should look like?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a module of level $X$ costs $100(X+1)$.  So $A$ modules of level $X$ cost $100A(L+1)$ and $35$ modules of level $67$ cost $35 \cdot 6800 = 238000$